# How to recall the username previously entered in another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing a value for username in one activity through XML. I want to recall the value in the next screen, like, 'Hello/Welcome, '. How is it possible using GetExtra and PutExtra?

Pls. find the below code, which I have tried for the same.

For storing the value of username in one activity:

```
Intent myActivity2 = new Intent(this,Activity1.class);
myActivity2.putExtra("nickname", R.id.mynickname3);
startActivity(myActivity2);
```

For recalling the value in other activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String val = extras.getString("nickname");
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setText(val);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reuse a username, use sharedPreference.

It is not a good idea to pass a userName to another activity then use that.Field like userName may need to use again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly right.

It is not enough to just pass the id of the EditText. You have to use below code -

`((EditText)findViewById(R.id.mynickname3)).getText().toString();`

int putExtra. Everything else should be fine.

UPDATE: Don't forget to set your TextView as contentView in OnCreate via:

```
setContentView(..)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need a bit elaboration on the part of coding, to make changes. I am a beginner! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity, you are passing in an integer value (*R.id.mynickname3*). Instead you need to give it a String. Use this instead:

```
myActivity2.putExtra("nickname", getString(R.id.mynickname3));
```

As a side note, you are trying to get a Bundle unnecessarily. Try this:

```
String val = getIntent().getStringExtra("nickname");
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
if (val != null)
{
    tv.setText(val);
}
```

Comment: I made the changes, as noted by you. But, the value is not displayed. Stacktrace:03-23 19:58:31.249: E/PerformBackupThread(61):  at com.android.server.BackupManagerService$BackupHandler.handleMessage(BackupManagerService.java:314)
03-23 19:58:31.249: E/PerformBackupThread(61):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 19:58:31.249: E/PerformBackupThread(61):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-23 19:58:31.249: E/PerformBackupThread(61):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

Comment: @Mannii88, does R.id.mynickname3 refer to a `String` or an `EditText`? The code I provided assumes String, however if it is an EditText, you should use `myActivity2.putExtra("nickname", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mynickname3)).getText());` If this does not fix it, this Handler error may be unrelated.

Comment: can you please tell for how to give the code for GetExtra too...??

Comment: @Mannii88 I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you be more specific? Your original `getExtras()` will work too. My `getStringExtra()` stuff above just reduces the number of commands needed to get the username.

Comment: i had the doubt...Since in my original, the getExtras refer to String, and here the variable is used in EditText, is there any need of typecast

Comment: @Mannii88 when you get the text from the `EditText`, it is a `CharSequence`. You could try `myActivity2.putExtra("nickname", (String) ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mynickname3)).getText());` (a String is basically a `nonmutable charsequence`).

Answer (score 0):

Just a silly mistake in your code:

```
myActivity2.putExtra("nickname", R.id.mynickname3);
```

Where you have written ID of the EditText (nickname), instead it should be as a:

```
 txtNickName = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.mynickname3);
 myActivity2.putExtra("nickname", txtNickName.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Hi Paresh, it will be helpful if you could bit elaborate on this, with corresponding activities(getExtra and PutExtra). Thanks! :)